# Getting string value from checklistbox checkeditems list

Tags: c#, validation

I'm attempting to setup validation where if a certain value is checked by the user, another value on the same page but in another checkboxlist must also be checked before data can be saved.

I'm trying to setup a nested foreach in this manner where my code goes through a loop and if value 1 is selected, it then checks for value2 with a foreach, if that value isn't selected I throw an error message.

This looks like it would work, but itemChecked.tostring() isn't set in this manner. What am I doing wrong here? (note string test is there just in my testing phase)

```
foreach (object itemChecked in clst1.CheckedItems)
{
   string test = itemChecked.ToString();
   if (test == "value1")
   {
      foreach (object subItemChecked in clst2.CheckedItems)
      {
         if (subItemChecked.ToString() != "value2")
         {
            MessageBox.Show("if value 1 is selected value 2 must be selected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(clst1.CheckedItems.Cast<object>()
                     .Any(x=>object.Equals(x.ToString(),"value1"))&&
   !clst2.CheckedItems.Cast<object>()
                     .Any(x=>object.Equals(x.ToString(),"value2"))){ 
   MessageBox.Show("if value 1 is selected value 2 must be selected", 
                    "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Note that it's still unclear on the underlying data type of items in your checkedlistbox, if the text of the item is what you mean by `value`. The code is OK. Otherwise you have to provide more info.

Comment: Are you aware that you're doing reference comparison? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel miss the ToString, it's not reference comparison

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think to compare reference we use `object.ReferenceEquals`, `object.Equals` can be used to compare values, the public method `Equals` will be used, so we have to override the `Equals` correctly for custom type.

Comment: Yes, sorry by value I mean text of the item.

Comment: This code looks good, but it's never setting to the string of the selectedItem. x.ToString() is just equaling 2 in this case. What am I missing?

Comment: @pmlevere what? have you tried it yet? Why you mentioned `selecteditem` here? I thought we just cared about **`CheckedItems`**? BTW, the code I posted is all you should try (**no loop** here).